# How to get started implementing a video streaming server in c/c++?

Tags: c++, video-streaming

In my project I need a dedicated server that dispatches the streams over to multiple clients.

More specificly, I've a callback function that gets called to gather the stream data, but no idea how to stream it over to other applications.

What's the best way to get started on this ?

Comment: Are you sure you want it done in C/C++ because i have done it as a web service and i willbe able to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

What type of video are you planning to stream?

There's an open source library called liveMedia available at http://www.live555.com. This c++ library is available under LGPL and implements the RTSP, RTP/RTCP protocols and payload formats for many different media types. There is a class called DeviceSource IIRC that facilitates getting data into the library. There is an active mailing list and you should be able to find lots of information by searching the archives.

There are also a bunch of example test projects that illustrate how to stream mpeg, mp3, etc.

Should you choose to use standardized protocols, you might want to read up on [RTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550) and [RTSP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check communication through network sockets.

There is no network concept in C++, so you have to rely on your system API or libraries ( as boost.asio for instance )

Comment: I know both sockets and pipes can do, but how?

Comment: well check boost.asio for instance and starts sending some text data. Then you'll have to define a protocol and sends your images through the sockets